# Flatbuffers create vector of enums

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I am having troubles with creating vector of enums.
I.e. given following schema file:

```
enum Month : short
{
    January,
    February,
    March,
}

table SpecificMonths
{
    Months:[Month];
}

root_type SpecificMonths;
```

I am trying to create object of type SpecificMonths:

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
Month months[] = {Month_January, Month_March};
auto monthsVector = builder.CreateVector(months, 2);
auto specificMonths = CreateSpecificMonths(builder, monthsVector);
```

But it throws error:

```
error C2664: 'flatbuffers::Offset<SpecificMonths> CreateSpecificMonths(flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &,flatbuffers::Offset<flatbuffers::Vector<int16_t>>)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'flatbuffers::Offset<flatbuffers::Vector<Month>>' to 'flatbuffers::Offset<flatbuffers::Vector<int16_t>>'

note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Any way to do it? I prefer sollution without std::vector (no allocation).

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that by default, C++ enums don't have a specified underlying type, though it typically defaults to `int`. So your `months` array can't be passed to `CreateVector`, even if you casted it, since they have different size elements.

The simplest solution may be to declare it as `int16_t months[]` instead, and your compiler should hopefully be ok converting each enum value as an initializer without casting.

Alternatively, compile your schema with `--scoped-enums` to get a C++11 style enum that has the proper underlying type. I am guessing the compiler will still complain passing `months` to `CreateVector` in this case, because now the enum is strongly typed, but at least now you can safely cast it since the values are now the same size (e.g. `reinterpret_cast<const int16_t *>(months)`).